# Dynamically Select SQL Server Column Names When Value is Not Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a summary fact table in my SQL Server data warehouse that has Order QTY by Order Number and Product Type. I would like to use this to generate a table that shows order composition (qty of each type) as a text field for reporting.

The original data looks like this:

```
ORDER_NBR   PRODUCT_TYPE    ORDER_QTY
-----------------------------------------
ABC123      PANTS       1
ABC123      SHIRTS      1
DEF456      SHIRTS      2
HIJ789      JACKETS     1
HIJ789      SHIRTS      2
KLM012      PANTS       2
```

I was able to get as far as here by using dynamic pivot.

```
ORDER_NBR   JACKETS     PANTS       SHIRTS
-------------------------------------------------------
ABC123      (NULL)      1           1
DEF456      (NULL)      (NULL)      2
HIJ789      1           (NULL)      2
KLM012      (NULL)      2           (NULL)
```

I would now like to turn this data into the following:

```
ORDER_NBR   ORDER_COMPOSITION
----------------------------------
ABC123      1 PANTS, 1 SHIRTS
DEF456      2 SHIRTS
HIJ789      1 JACKETS, 2 SHIRTS
KLM012      2 PANTS
```

Is there a way to dynamically select the column name and value only when the value is not null, then concatenate them together into a sigle field?

Comment: Yes, of course there is going to be a convoluted and inefficient way of doing this, but perhaps you could explain why the database should do this heavy lifting instead of the client side / presentation tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to PIVOT the data to get this result. You can simply concatenate the result using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select 
  t1.order_nbr,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + cast(order_qty as varchar(10)) + ' ' + product_type
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.order_nbr = t2.order_nbr
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS order_composition
from yourtable t1
group by t1.order_nbr;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3895c/1). The PIVOT is totally unnecessary to get the result.  This query will get you the result without any need to use dynamic sql:

```
| order_nbr |    order_composition |
|-----------|----------------------|
|    ABC123 |    1 PANTS, 1 SHIRTS |
|    DEF456 |             2 SHIRTS |
|    HIJ789 |  1 JACKETS, 2 SHIRTS |
|    KLM012 |              2 PANTS |
```